# Build an object from an array with different slugs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js, javascript-objects

I have to turn an array of different slugs that comes from a [[...slug.tsx]] catch all routes in an object.
The array:

```
['security', 'security/company' , 'security/people', 'security/people/overview', 'security/company/about', 'security/product', 'security/people/overview/steps', 'security/product/getting-started']
```

My idea is to have an array of objects, like this:

```
const securitySections = [
  {
    title: "Company",
    href: '/security/company',
    links: [
      {
        title: "Overview",
        href: "/security/company/about",
        links: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "People",
    href: '/security/people',
    links: [
      {
        title: "Overview",
        href: "/security/people/overview",
        links: [
          {
            title: "Steps",
            href: "/security/people/overview/steps",
            links: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Product",
    href: '/security/product',
    links: [
      {
        title: "Getting Started",
        href: "/security/product/getting-started",
        links: [],
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Any idea of how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is 'security/people' not in the array? Where does 'Installation' come from?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected it now.

Comment: How does this relate to Next.js? Isn't this simply about generating an array of objects based on a given array of strings?

Comment: yes, could you help me please? @juliomalves